# Android Ktor Client making infinite calls

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform, ktor

I'm making a kotlin multiplatform app, and recently when I opened my network inspector I noticed that my app is making a request to [www.google.com](http://www.google.com) every second without stop, each request is 20kb so if the user is using 5g it would be a problem.

First I thought the cause was kamelImage because of image loading errors and retries, but after removing it (for test purposes) or even changing the defaultKamel it still happens.

Below is a print of my network inspector and call stack, I noticed that the user agent is Ktor.

How do I find the origin of this request loop?
Ps: this calls does not appear in my logcat which is strange because my ktorClient has a logger and the other calls that I make in the app are there.

[image: network inspector]
enter image description here

[image: call stack]

Edit 1: I removed ktor implementation from gradle and it stopped.
This is the implementation I removed:

```
io.ktor:ktor-client-android
```

I tried to change to this, but same thing happens (even if I dont create any HTTPClient for use):

```
io.ktor:ktor-client-okhttp
```

Comment: does something particular trigger the connection loop? does it run if you don't initialize your ktor client?

Comment: @Pawel no it doenst trigger, first i removed only the common Kotlin multiplatform implementations, but the calls didnt stop, only after i removed the android ktor implementation from gradle it stopped

Comment: I suggest searching for the `google.com` string in the whole project to determine the origin of that behavior.

Comment: @AlekseiTirman already did that, no matches.

Comment: It means that some library (not Ktor) makes those requests.

Comment: @AlekseiTirman how do i find wich library? in the ones i use only kamel explicitly needs it. but i already removed kamelImage and it contniues

Comment: I would remove all libraries, but Ktor, to check what the cause is.